# Exclude first post from wp query

Tags: php, wp-query, theme-development, query-posts, offsets

I am building a WordPress website and I want to show post in it. But the problem is that, I want to exclude the first post in query. I have not much knowledge of PHP. So please help me to de this.
This is the basic code that The theme is using;

```php
<?php
$blog_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 8
);

$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $blog_args );

while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $blog_posts->the_post();
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Please help me to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using general programming/common sense with a variable and an `if` statement, no WordPress knowledge is required.

If we create a variable named `$skip_next` and set it to `true`, then perform a check in the loop, we can set it to false and `continue` to skip the first.

```php
$skip_next = true;
while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) {
    if ( $skip_next ) {
        $skip_next = false;
        continuel
    }

    $blog_posts->the_post();
```

Now because `$skip_next` is false on the second post it will not be skipped

Answer (score 0):

Delete the first post form the `posts` property:

```php
$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $blog_args );
unset( $blog_posts->posts[0] );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to exclude the first post in query. For example if the query is displaying post either category wise or by date just hide the first one. Pls help me in this problem.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? If so, please b specific on what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And yes I have tried that. But it only exclude post of given id. But all I need is to exclude first post. Not by id. The first post in query should not be shown.

Comment: Updated answer.